# IE11 protractor selenium, unable to create new remote

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, internet-explorer-11

Am expecting, protractor conf.js to open the angular website through internet explorer 11

After I type protractor `conf.js` It opens up ie11, but instead of opening the URL, I have in my example_spec.js 'http://www.angularjs.org', am seeing ie11 is opening 'http://localhost:XXXXX/' (xxxx are numbers) and in the page it says, 'this is the initial start page for the WebDriver server', am expecting ie11 to be opened with 'http://www.angularjs.org'

Bug report

```
    E/Launcher - Unable to create new remote session, desired capabilities = capabilities [(count=1, browserName=internet explorer, version=11, platform='Any')], required capabilities= Capabilities [()].

`Node Version`: `v6.9.5` 

`Protractor Version`: `5.1.1`

`Angular Version`: ``

`Browser(s)`: `IE11`: 

`Operating System and Version`:  `Windows 7, os.arch: 'amd64',, os.version: 6.1`

`Your protractor configuration file;`
`exports.config` = `{`
seleniumAddress`: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
seleniumArgs`: `['Dwebdriver.ie.driver=c:\Users\12345\Appdata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\IEDriverServer3.1.0.exe']`,
`capabilities`: `{`
`'browserName'` : `'internet explorer'`,
`'platform' : 'Any'`,
`'version'` : `'11'`
`},`
`framework`: `'jasmine'`,
`specs`: `['example_spec.js]`,
`jasmineNodeOpts`: `{`
`defaultTimeInterval`: `30000`
`}`
`};`

A relevant example test
`describe('angularjs home page',function(){`
`it('should greet the named user',function (){`
`browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');`
`element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');`
`var greeting=element(by.binding('yourName'));`
`expect(greeting.getText().toEqual('Hello Julie!');`
`});`
`});`
```

Output from running the test
it opens up ie11 but the url inside it is 'http://localhost:XXXXX/' , content in the page is ' 'this is the initial start page for the WebDriver server'

Steps to reproduce the bug
run webdriver-manager start and then go to the path where the conf file is located and type 'protractor conf.js'

The URL you are running your tests against (if relevant)
'http://www.angularjs.org'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its as per design that IE opens a default page before navigation to the url provided in `browser.get()` of your spec.

And yes, IE settings are a pain, and on some missing config you will see a `Unable to create new remote session` and the browser showing only the default page.

There could be multiple reasons for this. I would suggest trying out all the below suggestions and refer already existing questions

- "Enable Protected Mode" for each zone
- disable IE debugger
- Zoom is set to 100%